# How to transfer part of logic to another file

Tags: reactjs

I show a small part of my code

```
function App({}) {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [Indx, setIndx] = useState(0);

  useEffect(({durion}) => {

        setList(durion.map((value, index) => (<Durion
              key= {`${value}`}
              Length={`${index}`}
              Name= {`${value}`}
              ...
              onClick= {() => {
                setIndx(index);
              }}/>
            ))
        );

  }, []);
```

how to write this part of the year to the ArrDurion.js file;

```
 (<Durion  key= {`${value}`}
              Length={`${index}`}
              Name= {`${value}`}
              ...
              onClick= {() => {
                setIndx(index);
              }}/>
            )
```

ArrDurion.js

```
const ArrDurion = (<Durion  key= {`${value}`}
                  Length={`${index}`}
                  Name= {`${value}`}
                  ...
                  onClick= {() => {
                    setIndx(index);
                  }}/>
```

)

then to import to the App.js file.
but I get an Error setIndx(index) that does not exist,

You can show three ways to write code. To have this part of the code written in the ArrDurion.js file, then use it in App.js.
if you know other ways to reduce the code can show your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `setindx, value, index` as a prop and convert to a stateless component

**ArrDurian.jsx**

```
import Durian from './durianFile';
export const ArrDurion = ({index, value, onClickProp}) => {
    return (
          <Durion  
             key= {`${value}`}
             Length={`${index}`}
             Name= {`${value}`}
             onClick= {() => onClickProp(index)}
          />
        );
};
```

and then import into the other file `App.js` and use as below

```
import { ArrDurion } from 'ArrDurion';
function App({}) {
 const [list, setList] = useState([]);
 const [Indx, setIndx] = useState(0);

  useEffect(({durion}) => {
    setList(durion.map((value, index) => 
          <ArrDurian onClickProp={setIndx} value={value} index={index} />
        )
    );
 }, []);
```

While importing be careful about `Default` and `Named` imports

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the objects you wish to be able to import in other files.

```
export const ArrDurion = (index, value) => <Durion  key= {`${value}`}
              Length={`${index}`}
              Name= {`${value}`}
              ...
              onClick= {() => {
                setIndx(index);
              }}/>
```

and then import into the other file with

```
import { ArrDurion } from 'ArrDurion';
```

Comment: it looks like he also need to pass props to the exported component, not just constant some value

Comment: I have to import setIndx into ArrDurion.js ?

Comment: I made it a function with parameters so you can pass in index and value with ArrDurion(index, value)

Comment: You can show all your code. I get a setIndx (index) error, does not exist,

Comment: extract it into a stateless component and pass `setIndex, value and index` as Prop.